# Prevent Text Spilling out of Parent Container

Tags: html, css

I have a container div that contains an unordered list, that contains multiple li's (simplified to one in the fiddle for simple demonstration). Basically the text in the li's is spilling out over the containing div, which is odd because I added

`white-space:normal`

which is supposed to mitigate the issue, but clearly doesn't, see http://jsfiddle.net/hQA6u/.

I then tried to give the li a set width, but that doesn't work either.

Basically, I just want the li's text to not extend past the maroon/brown color, and have it break into multiple lines.

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hQA6u/1/)

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

this will do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Just add "overflow:hidden;" to your css, or you can use "overflow:scroll;" to make div scrollable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `overflow:hidden` would hide part of the text, and `overflow:scroll` adds scroll bars. There must be a way to do this without this, right?